# Как выполнить API запрос с сервера iFrame приложения ВКонтакте?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

В iframe приложение ВКонтакте пользователь приходит с пачкой [GET-параметров](https://vk.com/dev/apps_init).

Можно ли в свежих версиях API, полагаясь только на эти параметры, ID и Защищённый ключ приложения, выполнять с сервера запросы к API от имени пользователя?

**Upd.** ипользование `access_token`, который был передан с упомянутыми параметрами – **не вариант**, т.к. он привязан к IP клиента. Его можно использовать в JS из браузера клиента, но нельзя с сервера приложения:

```
{
"error": {
    "error_code": 5,
    "error_msg": "User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address.",
    "request_params": [{
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "wall.getById"
    }, { ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тех. поддержка ВК развеяла сомнения: без OAuth авторизации выполнение запросов с сервера от имени пользователя в iFrame прилжоении невозможно.

[image: скрин диалога с тех. поддержкой ВК]

Answer (score 0):

Полагаться нужно на **access_token** и с его использованием, делать запросы к API:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=%ACCESS_TOKEN из GET-параметра%
```

Этот запрос получит информацию о пользователе, который сейчас в приложении.

Comment: `access_token`, который передан с запросом среди [этих параметров](https://vk.com/dev/apps_init) привязан к IP клиента и не работает с сервера. ПРобовал. Инфа 100%.

Comment: может, в свежих версиях api есть схема с подписью запроса, как это было в api v 3.0? С сортировкой параметров по алфавиту и `md5` от параметров + секрет приложения.

Comment: @Sergiks, если не ошибаюсь, то в 5.0 это сделано специально. И вроде бы ничего никуда не привязывается, просто если Ваш сервер в Германии, а юзер с России, то запрос не пройдёт и будет требовать проверку валидации (если прямо пользователь передал логин и пароль). Но в приложениях я такого не наблюдал.

Comment: @Sergiks, хм. Нашёл старые обсуждения http://vk.com/topic-15957347_25001738, но ни у кого так и не получилось. Тем более в новых ответах так же. Видимо отправлять запросы можно только с помощью JS. Можно попробовать детально всё узнать у поддержки ВК API — https://vk.com/support?act=new_api

Comment: поддержке вопрос задал вчера, пока молчат. Как будет от них решение – отпишусь здесь.